# Регулярное выряжение для определения номера телефона

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно написать код для определение номера телефона который начинается на 1,8,9 и состоит из 8 цифр, если правильно та Valid и неправильно то Invalid.

```
number = input()
if number[:1] == '1' or number[:1] == '8' or number [:1] == '9':
    print('Valid')
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

Comment: Для начала сюда: [Ask]

Comment: `pip install phonenumbers` (есди это конечно номера телефонов). Просто чето берут меня сомнения про восьмизначные номера телефонов

Answer (score 1):

- Зачем вы преобразуете ввод (который изначально строка) сначала в `int`, потом обратно в `str`? Будет не выведено "Invalid", если во вводе попадутся не цифры, а вылетит исключение при таком подходе.
- При перечислении вариантов в квадратных скобках нужно только сами символы указывать подряд, запятые не нужны
- Зачем вы ставите знаки вопроса? Они там не нужны
- "Состоит из 8 цифр" - но это же включая первую цифру, которую вы уже обозначили шаблоном через перечисление вариантов, значит дальше идёт ещё 7 цифр, а не 8, как у вас задано в шаблоне

Answer (score 0):

Код для вас:

```
number = input()
if number[:1] == '1' or number[:1] == '8' or number[:1] == '9':
    print('Valid')
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

Даже импорты не нужны)

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но при вводе больше чем 8 цифр если они начинаются на 1,8,9 выедает правильный ответ